# Algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $x$ be transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $K$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(x)$. How to show that $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If $B$ is a transcendence basis of $\mathbb C$ over $\mathbb Q$, then $B$ is uncountable, and $\mathbb C$ is an algebraic closure of $\mathbb Q(B)$.

Now $B\cup\{x\}$ is a transcendence basis of $K$ over $\mathbb Q$. Since $B$ and $B\cup\{x\}$ have the same cardinal, $K$ and $\mathbb C$ are isomorphic: they are both algebraic closures of purely transcendental extensions of $\mathbb Q$ of the same transcendence degree.

Comment: I do not understand why B union {x} is a basis .I understand why B union {x} is linearly independent over Q. Secondly I do not understand why "Since B and B∪{x} have the same cardinal,K and C are isomorphic. I have done an only introductory course in galois theory

Comment: Notice that I am not talking of bases of vector spaces: throughout, I am talking about *trascendence bases*.

Comment: Suppose K1, K2 are two algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic and
#K1 = #K2 is uncountable. Then K1 is isomorphic to K2.If we apply this theorem for K and C then we get the ans. Is it so?

Comment: That is the point of Bill's answer, not mine. In any case, do you know how to prove that, which is Steinitz's theorem? The argument I sketched in my answer is considerably more elementary and depends on a little of basic field theory.

Comment: I have one doubt in the proof.If S1 and S2 are uncountable sets,Does there exists a set bijection between x(i) {i runs over S1} and  x(i) {i runs over S2}. x(i)`s are variables

Comment: Only if S1 and S2 are of the same cardinal.

Comment: If two sets are uncountable then they have the same cardinality right?

Comment: No. Uncountable means only «not countable» and there are many other cardinalities! For example $\mathbb R$ and the set $\mathcal P(\mathbb R)$ of all subsets of $\mathbb R$ are uncountable of different cardinalities.

Answer (score 5):

This is an immediate consequence of a famous theorem of Steinitz that uncountable algebraically closed fields are isomorphic iff they have equal characteristic and equal cardinality (a prototypical example of [Morley's categoricity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morley%27s_categoricity_theorem)).

This fails in the countable case, e.g. if $\mathbb A = $ algebraic numbers then, though countable, $\overline{\mathbb A(x)}\not\cong \mathbb A$ since they have unequal transcendence degree over $\mathbb Q,\:$ viz. $1$ vs. $0$, resp.