# Fields and proper subfields.

Tags: field-theory, extension-field, class-field-theory

Specific question: Let $F$ be a field and assume that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a proper subfield of $F$. Can $F$ be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}$?

---

Studying the foundaments of field theory I have to ask: Can a field be isomorphic to one of its proper subfields?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/137906/algebraic-closure-of-mathbbcx-is-isomorphic-to-mathbbc) for an example - namely, that the algebraic closure of $\Bbb C(x)$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb C$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, given any field $k$, $k(x)$ is isomorphic to $k(x^2)$.